# access records based on user id - roles setup

Tags: custom-object, sharing, user-record, role-hierarchy

I am new to Salesforce, and need an advise.

We are planning to create a custom object and custom tab for it. Now, we want user to be able to access only his/her record, or records related to him. For example, student can only see his record, but professor can see all his/her records. Can I do it with sharing?

Thanks,
V.

**EDIT 1**

I created two roles:
[image]

I assigned roles to users:

[image]

The object has default access as Private and allows hierarchy:

[image]

I created two records, one with Student ownership, and one with Instructor ownership:

[image]

and

[image]

**I would expect that student can only see his record and Instructor can see both records. However, in my case both user can see both records. I do not understand what is wrong in my setup. Thanks:**

[image]

and

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is very fundamental.Keep the org wide default (OWD)  as private for the object.Have a role hirerachy and keep professor at top of role hirerachy than student.

Also make sure you have checked grant access using hirerachy as true.

OWD you can find under sharing settings and also you can find roles under administrative settings.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What if professors and students do not create their records. Owner field will not have their names. I assume hierarchy sharing rules work with Owner field. How I can reach the same result using student and professor IDs ?

Comment: owner ids you can always load through data loader i feel for records.

Comment: its not possible with just Ids

Comment: Mohith, what if I have multiple professors and multiple students, and professors suppose to see only their students, can I only use two roles "Professor" and "Student"? If yes, how do I limit professor to see only his student in the role hierarchy?

Comment: @vlr whats the profile of professors and students?make sure that profile of dont have view All access or modify all for the object ?If view All or modify All exists then role hirerachy holds no importance .If multiple professors come in then you may need concept of territory management i feel.

Comment: You can use Apex Managed Sharing if you need complex logic that's not based on ownership. Basically, you create a "sharing reason", then write code that uses that sharing reason to manage who can see the record. For example, there might be a "Professor Student" table that links professors to their students. You can query this data and build sharing based on that object.